# Asp.Net Web Api, Return or inklude value from Foreign tabel "Code-First database"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'am trying to return singel employee including value from  Foreign tabel.

Here is my Modelclass for Employee

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Gender")]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }


    }
```

Department and Gender Model class

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }

public class Gender
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string GenderName { get; set; }
    }
```

With this below code I can return inklusive departmentname and gendername when I return

```
all employees
// GET: api/Employees
        public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return db.Employees.Include(c => c.Department).Include(g => g.Gender); ;
        }
```

But I don't know how to return when I want to return one singel employee... I'am geting department and gender to null.
Here is my code.. I don't know how to include departmentName and genderName in this singel employee. I just get DepartmentId, andGenderId inkluded, but not DepartmentName and GenderName.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployee(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(employee);
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

return await db.Employees.Include(c => c.Department).Include(g => g.Gender).SingleAsync(e => e.EmployeeId == id);